# Angular 2 - Kendo UI grid. Issue with sort implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am developing an angular 2 app using asp.net in visual studio. The HTML that is rendered is using Kendo UI datagrid. I am trying to implement, scrolling and sorting. The scrolling works perfectly fine. However have issue when trying to implement sorting. I am getting an error

The error is "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode. Duplicate identifier Data". This is compile time error

This error refers to data property assignment in the loadRisks() method. I am new to typescript and need some help. How do I assign the order by clause to the datagrid. Could somebody help.

**risk-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';
import { GridModule, GridDataResult, PageChangeEvent, SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'rm-risks',
    templateUrl: '/app/risk-list.component.html',
    providers: [RiskService]
})

export class RiskListComponent implements OnInit {
    private gridView: GridDataResult;
    private sort: SortDescriptor[] = [];
    private data: any[];
    private pageSize: number = 10;
    private skip: number = 0;
    title = 'Risk List';
    risks: Risk[];

    constructor(private _riskService: RiskService) {
        this.data = [];
        this.getRisks();
        this.loadRisks();
     }

    protected pageChange(event: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.skip = event.skip;
        this.loadRisks();
    }

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        this.sort = sort;
        this.loadRisks();
    }


    private loadRisks(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize), 
            data: orderBy(this.risks, this.sort),
            total: this.data.length
        };
    }

    getRisks(): void {
        this._riskService.getRisks().then(risks => this.risks = risks);

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getRisks();
    }
};
```

**risk-list.component.html**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="risks"
            [skip]="skip"
            [pageSize]="pageSize"
            [scrollable]="'virtual'"
            [rowHeight]="36"
            [height]="300"
            (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
            [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
            [sort]="sort"
            (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
    <kendo-grid-column field="reference" title="Reference" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="insuredName" title="Insured Name" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="inceptionDate" title="Inception Date" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="riskType" title="Risk Type" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="status" title="Indication" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="grossPremium" title="Gross Premium" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="allocatedTo" title="Allocated To" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="allocatedCompany" title="Allocated Company" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="100">
        <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled />
        </template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**risk.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk';
import { Risks } from './mock-risk';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';


@Injectable()
export class RiskService {

    getRisks(): Promise<Risk[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(Risks);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share complete error?

Comment: The error is "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode. Duplicate identifier Data". This is compile time error

Comment: Most likely error due to variable data in your component. Try renaming data from this line- `private data: any[]`

Comment: How does that help. If i rename , then it complains there is no variable data in the code following. If I create a another variable that is data1 fr example like this   data: this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize), 
            data1: orderBy(this.risks, this.sort), then I get error message Type {'data:any[];data1:Risk[];total:number;}' is not assignable to type GridDataResult. Object literals may only specify known properties  and Data1 does not exist in type GridDataResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you cannot have duplicate properties like you have in your `loadRisks` method. Look at the duplicate `data` property here in your object.

```
private loadRisks(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize), 
            data: orderBy(this.risks, this.sort),
            total: this.data.length
        };
    }
```

You should merge those expressions or create a function that returns the data value you need. An example could be:

```
private loadRisks(): void {
    this.gridView = {
        data: this.handleData(),
         total: this.data.length
    };
}

private handleData() {
    var pagedData = this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize)
    if (!this.sort) { return pagedData; }

    var orderedAndPagedData = orderBy(pagedData, this.sort);
    return orderedAndPagedData;
}
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtaExNxX9eOQrCzYwO1N?p=preview

Comment: I understand thats the reason. My question is how do I merge that expression

Comment: Thanks for sharing the your implementation. I can see that it is working for you on plunker but unfirtunately it doesnt work for me. When I click on the sort arrows it does nothing. I believe there is some issue with the binding. Not sure what the problem is

Comment: I can see that you are working with risks and data objects. You should consider only using one object. You're missing something obvious as the plunkr proves the concept :-)

Comment: I have tried to use just the data object but that lands up in an error. I dont see any data on the grid. I have updated the post to include the service class. Could you let me know what the problem could be

Comment: if you can reproduce it in a plunkr, I will have a look

Comment: I have recreated the problem. Please see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/9qnCARCXKc1ZQzB8Ah3D?p=preview

Comment: @Tom here is an updated working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/b1WBeNHLrD3RkUP0epIK?p=preview
you bind [data] to data instead of gridView object.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using [data]="risks" use [kendodatagrid]="risks"